# The type or namespace name 'wikidbModel' could not be found in .net framework using visual studio 2012

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I Try to use this code for .net Entity FrameWork

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//using wikidbModel;
//using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;



public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       wikidbModel.wikidbEntities db = new wikidbModel.wikidbEntities();

        var lst = from m in db.Movies
                  select m;


    }
}
```

but i have this error :
**Error 1 The type or namespace name 'wikidbModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
and not correct whit use this:

```
using wikidbModel;
```

Please help me!

Comment: Do you have a namespace *wikidbModel* in your project? If it's in another project: Do you have added a reference to this project?

Comment: I dont know i have a namespace or not! please tell me about that.

Comment: In your project, look for a folder named wikidbModel. There you should find your wikidbEntities class. If it's a generated class search for your wikidbEntities class. This class should normally be placed in a namespace. Check if you use the right namespace. If you have any problems, it could be helpful to post your wikidbEntities class.

Comment: i found this **// Default code generation is disabled for model 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSiteEF1\App_Code\TestModel.edmx'. 
// To enable default code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
// property to an alternate value. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model is
// open in the designer.**

Comment: Tank you Mr Horizon_Net, I solved that.